# npe when iterating through entities of a has-many relationship

Tags: database, grails, nullpointerexception, grails-orm, spring-orm

I have this code in my grails application:

```
    article.findings.find { it.findingId.equals(findingId) }
```

that throws exception:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'findingId' on null object`.
**Article table** has a association of type : **hasMany** **findings** (List  findings).
I've search in the database for:

- having an entry in article table with given article id
- having entries in findings table for given article id, all entries there have of course finding_id. Between those entries there is my entry with given finding_id.

In the database all seems good. Any idea why?

Comment: `gorm doesn't read the article from Article table` well it does. You would get an NPE on `article.findings` otherwise

Comment: yes @injecteer, you are right. but I still don't know why this happens.

Comment: print out the `article.findings` collection and you gonna see some null values inside. Also `println atricle.findings*.id` will help you identifying ids of missing objects

Comment: how can article.findings have empty entries if in the db there is no entry for that article with finding_id null ? also finding_id is a primary key. I cannot print since this happens on production environment but on my local machine, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that on finding table, there is a column named findings_idx that should have values from 0 to noOfFindings-1 but in reality for that particular article the findings_idx was missing for the first entry (it was probably deleted from db). Somehow gorm/hibernate/grails expects the indexes to start from 0.

Comment: "Somehow gorm/hibernate/grails expects the indexes to start from 0" - FYI... Zero based indices are quite common.

Comment: I am aware that indexes start from 0 in programming, but in this case it it something I don't understand entirely yet. How hibernate knows that findings_idx is a column that should have indexes starting from 0 and all values should be incremental? Because on the ddl, the column is just like any other column declared, of integer type. @JeffScottBrown